# Attempting to fire Mobx action causes Uncaught Type Error

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I'm attempting to fire off a Mobx action, and it's generating the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrowVisible' of undefined." Can't figure out why (function is being triggered by react-waypoint):

([codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/v0yqvoqr5) replication here)

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "reactstrap";
import { observer, inject } from "mobx-react";
import Waypoint from "react-waypoint";

@inject("styleStore")
@observer
export class Questions extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      entered: false
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }

  setWaypointEnter() {
    // Set waypoint state
    this.setState({ entered: true });
    // Use updated state for UI waypoints animation.
    if (this.state.entered) {
      this.props.styleStore.isArrowVisible("yes");
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <QuestionsDiv id="questions">
          <Container>
            <Waypoint
              scrollableAncestor={window}
              onEnter={this.setWaypointEnter.bind(this)}
              fireOnRapidScroll={true}
              topOffset="40%"
            />
...
```

This is the MobX store:

```
import { observable, action } from "mobx";

class StyleStore {
  @observable nextLink;
  @observable arrowVisibile;

  @action
    isArrowVisibile(visibility) {
    this.arrowVisibile = visibility;
    console.log(this.arrowVisibile);
  }
}

export default StyleStore;
```

And index.js to loading the Provider:

```
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "mobx-react";
import StyleStore from "./stores/styleStore";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";

const stores = {
  styleStore: new StyleStore()
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider {...stores}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>,

  document.getElementById("root")
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

I'm also using [react-app-rewire-mobx](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/tree/master/packages/react-app-rewire-mobx). So .babelrc looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["mobx"]
}
```

What am I missing here that would case this error? The other MobX action, ChangeNextLink, works as coded.

Comment: maybe it should be `@inject("StyleStore")` ?

Comment: It's actually "styleStore" in index.js -- e.g.:
`const stores = {
  styleStore: new StyleStore()
};`

Comment: Can you inclue store construction and Provider code as well? Or better: create a codesandbox ?

Comment: Are you using babel? If so please show me your configurations to handle decurators and other such plugins.

Comment: Also, are you using `<Provider {...stores}><App/></Provider>`

Comment: I've updated my question with <Provider> and babel config.

Comment: Also, added codesandbox.io link

Comment: @Robbie Did you try the answer i gave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be here

```
 this.props.styleStore.arrowVisible();
```

arrowVisible is an observable property and not an action, You might have meant to call

```
 this.props.styleStore.isArrowVisible();
```

Also there is a spelling error in your store

```
@action
    isArrowVisibile(visibility)
```

should be

```
@action
    isArrowVisible(visibility)
```

Comment: Made this change in the sandbox -- still getting error "Cannot read property 'isArrowVisible' of undefined."

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/v0yqvoqr5)

Comment: @Robbie There is a spelling mistake in your stores action
It should be isArrowVisible and not isArrowVisibile also you forgot to inject the store in your sandbox.

Comment: Ah! Typo it was. Thank you for the catch!